# Angular Material table, run time pushed row when sorting

Tags: angular, sorting, material-ui

I have a table created with Angular material, like this:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of displayedColumns; let i = index" cdkColumnDef="{{getColumnName(i)|Formater:'clean'}}">
    <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="example-header-cell"> {{item.split('__')[0]}} </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">
      {{row.values[i]|Formater:'delta'}}
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<mat-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" class="example-header-row"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;let index=index"
    class="example-row" (click)="onClick(row, index)" #cdkrow></mat-row>
```

and I followed [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZL6OnWwVmOCPYetp96XX?p=preview) example to add a detail table when the row clicked, the problem is when its in run time added, and after the column was sorted, the new detail in the old place where the row was before sort, can any one help how to get the new place of the row after sort, so I can maybe use it to push the newly run time created object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add or remove DOM elements that are part of *ngFor, you must use trackBy option, to help Angular to keep the track of elements.

So add this in the view on *ngFor:

```
"....;trackBy: trackByFn"
```

and this in the class:

```
  trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index;
  }
```

> When the contents of the iterator changes, NgForOf makes the
>   corresponding changes to the DOM....
>
> Otherwise, the DOM element for that item will remain the same. Angular
>   uses object identity to track insertions and deletions within the
>   iterator and reproduce those changes in the DOM.
>
> To customize the default tracking algorithm, NgForOf supports trackBy
>   option. trackBy takes a function which has two arguments: index and
>   item. If trackBy is given, Angular tracks changes by the return value
>   of the function.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> <li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i; trackBy:
> > trackByFn">...</li> <li template="ngFor let item of items; index as i;
> > trackBy: trackByFn">...</li> With <ng-template> element:
>
>
>
> >  content_copy <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items"
> > let-i="index" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">   <li>...</li>
> > </ng-template>
> ```

---

Read more here : https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#change-propagation

and here: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5